# Extending an X509Certificate2 using a UUID OID

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, x509

I would like to create an X509Certificate2 with a custom extension. Basically I'd just like to add information to a certificate that
isn't covered by other basic extensions.

Any extension requires an OID. Since the data I want to embedd in my certificate does not match an existing/registered OID, i would like to use a UUID based OID. These are well specified and don't require formal registration. One can just use "2.25.<UUID as integer>". Examples for registered OIDs can be seen here: https://oidref.com/2.25

Unfortunately, trying to add an extension with such an OID fails in .NET 6.0

```
using var certKey = RSA.Create(4096);
var certReq = new CertificateRequest(
  "CN=Test",
  certKey,
  HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
  RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1
);

certReq.CertificateExtensions.Add(
  new X509Extension(
    new AsnEncodedData(
      "2.25.40669347737942061524839982746896813736",
      Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
        System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(
          new { TestData = "foo" })
        )
    ),
    false
  )
);

var cert = certReq.CreateSelfSigned(
  DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
  DateTimeOffset.MaxValue
);
```

Accessing cert.Extensions throws
`System.ArgumentException: 'The 'oid.Value' string cannot be empty or null. (Parameter 'oid')'`

From trial and error, I deduce that .NET OID validation cannot cope with that large integer (reducing that large integer from the UUID to about 13 places seems to do the trick ;) )

So my question comes in two parts:

1. Am I right in assuming that this a bug and if so where would be the best place to report it?
2. How should I deal with this?

   1. I figured i could use each group from a v4 UUID as a separate number, i.e. a UUID like `396fe716-07a0-456b-9fb6-8394b0983161` would become a OID of `2.25.963634966.1952.17771.40886.144674641162593`. .NET seems to swallow that just fine and it would still be a unique OID (albeit not one conforming to their standard)
   2. use another - existing - OID for arbitrary metadata? I couldn't find any. Suggestions?
   3. register my own OID? (ugh, what a hassle!)
   4. Just use some other made up OID and assume it won't ever conflict with something else? (the certificates generated are not really for public use anyways)

Comment: "Am I right in assuming that this a bug and if so where would be the best place to report it?"  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues.  Don't remember if we can't fix it because Windows doesn't support UUID-OIDs (or, rather, any OID with an arc bigger than 2^^32 or 2^^64)... or we just needed someone to care to justify changing the codepath from the old encoder to a new one.

Comment: Yeah, `CryptEncodeObject` native function and .NET `CryptoConfig.EncodeOID` (which has its own encoder) are limited to signed 64-bit integer for OID arc.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check to see if someone else has reported this and if not, i'll open up a new one. 

@Crypt32 it sounds like what you're saying is that this is so elemental that it probably won't get changed.

There must be people out there using UUID OIDs in certificates, no? Since you guys seem to know your stuff: any recommendations for an OID i should use for custom data?

Comment: `There must be people out there using UUID OIDs in certificates, no?` -- I have 10yrs of experience in PKI and never faced such issue. I'm not saying it is wrong, just not something commonly used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is a limitation to OID arc length in Windows and limit is 2^63 bits for single arc which is not sufficient for UUID (which requires 128 bits). At least, fundamental `CryptEncdeObject` function has such limit and this function is extensively used in Windows CryptoAPI.

Here is an example in PowerShell:

```
$signature = @"
[DllImport("Crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CryptEncodeObject(
    int dwCertEncodingType,
    int lpszStructType,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    ref string pvStructInfo,
    byte[] pbEncoded,
    ref int pcbEncoded);
"@

Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Namespace PKI -Name Crypt32
$pcbEncoded = 0
$pvStructInfo = "2.25.40669347737942061524839982746896813736"
[PKI.Crypt32]::CryptEncodeObject(1,73,[ref] $pvStructInfo,$null,[ref] $pcbEncoded)
$pbEncoded = New-Object byte[] -ArgumentList $pcbEncoded
[PKI.Crypt32]::CryptEncodeObject(1,73,[ref] $pvStructInfo,$pbEncoded,[ref] $pcbEncoded)
```

The function didn't fail, just truncated your value to 2^63:
[image]

Even if you use other tools that doesn't have limits to craft a cryptographic object with very long arc, you will run into compatibility issues when using on Windows.

In this case, I would avoid the use of UUID namespace for custom extensions and register your own branch at IANA and define your custom OIDs within assigned branch. Here is the application form to register your own private enterprise number (PEN): https://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page. The application is free.

Comment: Worked like a charm and took only a few hours to get the PEN assigned. Thank you!